# OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan SSLRead() return error -9841

Tags: curl, macos, https, terminal

Есть результат передачи запроса POST на https сайт через терминал

```
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9841
```

curl --version

```
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

Какие шаги нужно предпринять что бы curl заработал?

P.S Ранее переустанавливал его командой `brew install --with-openssl curl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказалось что надо было перезагрузить компьютер после повторной установки curl. Теперь все работает.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/102250)

Comment: @ИванПшеницын это ответ автора на свой же вопрос, так что является ответом.

Comment: @Denis меня смутило не авторство а содержание "ответа". Это с сильной натяжкой можно назвать таковым. Особенно в текущей формулировке.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын "...критикуешь — предлагай...", что конкретно посоветуете вы на этот счет?

Comment: За что минусы, коллеги?

Comment: "надо было перезагрузить компьютер" - это не ответ. зачем его надо было перезагружать? может быть можно было перелогиниться, может быть можно было открыть новое окно терминала,  может проблема была не в curl.

Comment: Не, господа, это однозначно **ответ**. Он содержит действия, которые привели к исчезновению проблемы. Возможно, в этих действиях спрятано что-то более глубокое и осмысленное, просто автор не смог до этого добраться. А возможно, это вообще совпадение и реально произошло что-то ещё. Из-за этой неоднозначности это **плохой ответ, но ответ**.